# Is it possible in SQLAlchemy to filter by a database function or stored procedure?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

We're using SQLalchemy in a project with a legacy database. The database has functions/stored procedures. In the past we used raw SQL and we could use these functions as filters in our queries.
I would like to do the same for SQLAlchemy queries if possible. I have read about the @hybrid_property, but some of these functions need one or more parameters, for example;

I have a User model that has a JOIN to a bunch of historical records. These historical records for this user, have a date and a debit and credit field, so we can look up the balance of a user at a specific point in time, by doing a `SUM(credit) - SUM(debit)` up until the given date.
We have a database function for that called `dbo.Balance(user_id, date_time)`. I can use this to check the balance of a user at a given point in time.

I would like to use this as a criterium in a query, to select only users that have a negative balance at a specific date/time.

```
selection = users.filter(coalesce(Users.status, 0) == 1,
                         coalesce(Users.no_reminders, 0) == 0,
                         dbo.pplBalance(Users.user_id, datetime.datetime.now()) < -0.01).all()
```

This is of course a non-working example, just for you to get the gist of what I'd like to do. The solution looks to be to use hybrd properties, but as I mentioned above, these only work without parameters (as they are properties, not methods).

Any suggestions on how to implement something like this (if it's even possible) are welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a @hybrid_property isn't by itself a means of producing a particular SQL statement, it is only a helper that can add more query-generation capabilities to an ORM-mapped class.

SQL functions that can be called as plain functions (e.g. without any kind of "EXEC XYZ" type of syntax) can be called using the [func](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=func#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) construct, meaning the query you have is pretty much ready to go:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
selection = users.filter(coalesce(Users.status, 0) == 1,
                         coalesce(Users.no_reminders, 0) == 0,
                         func.dbo.pplBalance(Users.user_id, datetime.datetime.now()) < -0.01).all()
```